# callback json value by name/key

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, callback

With this function I'm trying to get the licence name from a json url by name/key
my json looks like this:

```
[{"Gallery":true,"Responsive":true,"Main":true,"Seasonal":true}]
```

js:

```
function getLicenseName(name, callback){
    var license = 'default'
    $.getJSON(adl+'DesignTemplateBuilder.aspx?GetLicense=1', function(data){
        /*
        licence = data[0].Gallery;
        respValue = data[0].Responsive;
        seasonalValue = data[0].Seasonal;
        */
        licence = data[0].name;
        callback(licence)
    }); 
}
getLicenseName(name, function(Responsive) {
    console.log(name);
    //this returns empty right now
});
```

What I need is to get the `true` or `false` value using something like this

```
getLicenceName(Gallery);
```

I need to use it in my functions eg: `if(getLicenceName(Gallery)=false)...`

Comment: There is no `name` key in your JSON.

Comment: what is `data[0].name`?

Comment: if i use data[0].Gallery works, so I was trying to replace Gallery with name to use another names too

Comment: your js code won't execute the line `callback(name)`. because it's got an error on line `name = data[0].name`. some error message can be `data[0].name is undefined`

Answer (score 1):

```
function getLicenseName(callback){
    $.getJSON(adl+'DesignTemplateBuilder.aspx?GetLicense=1', function(data){
        callback(data)
    }); 
}
getLicenseName(function(data) {
    console.log(data[0].Gallery);
    //this returns empty right now
});
```

Will do the trick.

Comment: this returns "undefined"

Comment: this works, but I need to simplify a bit the return..to use it like this `if(getLicenceName(Gallery)=false)`

Comment: That's whole new question, please post it as a different OP. Please mark it as a corrct answer if it work for the OP.

Comment: I said that in my description, I need to call multiple functions and I don't want to run this functions again and again

Comment: this is not working in chrome, IE, all good in firefox - any ideea why?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do `if(getLicenceName(Gallery) == false)` because the AJAX request is asynchronous, but you can do it this way:

```
function getLicenseName(name, callback) {
    $.getJSON(adl+'DesignTemplateBuilder.aspx?GetLicense=1', function(data){

       // pass back the name parameter
       callback(data[0][name])
    }); 
}

// use quotes around the name
getLicenseName('Gallery', function (name) {
    if (name) {
      ...
    }
});
```

Comment: is it possbile to get only the value eg: true when I call `getLicenseName(Gallery)` ?

Comment: No, because the AJAX request is asynchronous. You're better off grabbing this information at the start of your code and storing it in a global var for use later on.

Comment: It should work in all browsers. Are you getting any errors in the console @Adrian?